# Could we get someone to curate the fallacies tag?

Tags: discussion

It was asked at one point:

["What fallacy is this?" - on topic or off topic?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/what-fallacy-is-this-on-topic-or-off-topic)

Accepting that we will consider these to be in principle on topic, could we curate these entries in some way to make the more helpful? For instance, we could settle on a standard title format or somehow organize the questions under this heading so as to avoid duplicates on the same fallacy when there is roughly speaking agreement about which fallacy?

Answer (score 2):

We could create different tags for the main categories, because they're often already clear to the OP.

Concerning the title, we should encourage people to describe some general form of the fallacy in the question. Not "What fallacy is this?" because it's not descriptive; but also not "What fallacy does Alice make when she says that Bob blah blah while she blah blah blah" because it isn't very helpful either.

Comment: I think we may need to edit titles to the most generic versions for fallacies... it's doubtful OPs will give us that

Comment: Yes, definitely. But that's okay, it's not like we receive thousands of questions a day :)

Answer (score 2):

I've gone through and edited the titles of every fallacy-tag question that was asking "is this a fallacy?" to include a brief sketch of the instance in question. 
More could always be done.

A small subset of the questions were about the nature of fallacies rather than whether some particular pattern is a fallacy.

An even smaller subset had nearly nothing to do with fallacies so I removed the tag. (For some, it was used synonymously with thinking an argument is bad without reference to any of the things we call fallacies and with no focus on the "identify the fallacy game")